# Resource list errors cannot be fixed , makes me unable to install anything

Tags: 14.04, 16.04, apt, software-sources

I tried methods like deleting or updating the source list that I found on the web but these didn't fix it.

[image: screenshot, malformed entry in atom list, no further output from sudo apt-get update]

Comment: Could you please post text files, dialogue messages, and program output listings as text, not as images? To achieve the latter two you can either 1) select, copy & paste the dialogue text or terminal content or 2) [save the program output to a file](//askubuntu.com/q/420981/175814) and use that. Longer listings (the editor will tell you what’s too long) should be uploaded to a [pastie service](https://paste.ubuntu.com/) and linked to in the question. Thanks.

Comment: Why is your post tagged 14.04 and 16.04? Which one are you using? Please let us know if the answer given by Thomas was effective. Your question is not clear because you haven't told us exactly what you did.

Comment: ok thanks, i will pay attention to do the right way next time , thanks for  your suggestions^^

Answer (score 0):

in your case it seems that you just have to remove the atom source list

```
sudo rm -f /etc/apt/sources.list.d/atom.list
sudo apt-get update
```

if you want the atom txt editor to be installed/updated, follow the link: https://launchpad.net/~webupd8team/+archive/ubuntu/atom?field.series_filter=trusty